How to disable/remove Recovery mode in Android?
I want to prevent myself and anyone from accessing Recovery mode on my android phone. Because basically, I don't want my phone to be reset to the factory state (wipe data) and sideload the firmware. Is there any app/method which can do this task? And is it possible and safe to lock the bootloader after completely removing the stock recovery partition?

Possible duplicate: How can I disable recovery mode?

Unless you have unlocked the bootloader firmware sideloading is restricted to official firmware updates that are anyway automatically installed by the software update system of Android.

as I know Google Pixel don't need to unlock the bootloader to sideload OTA images

This question is similar to: How can I disable recovery mode?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I will try to flash stock boot.img to recovery partition by using: fastboot flash recovery boot.img. But I don't know if my phone can boot or not once I locked the bootloader

Normally fastboot flash only works on devices with unlocked bootloader (no matter if the data to be flashed is stock or a custom ROM/partition).

I know it, I mean after flashing I will relock the bootloader, is it possible and safe?
